# How to select and count a column in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

So I have two tables,
From the first table `app_catalog`, I want to select all the data,
the complete the condition for the second table name `statistics_log`

So at the second table, I want to select `app_id` that relates to the first table and the most important thing I want to count the field log_type for each app and do a grouping and get 10 with max number.

I am really trying to get this done, I would appreciate every help thank you!!

Comment: "_I am trying, but I am not so good with a query_" Still, you should post what you tried.

Comment: I will add more info just in few min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you but i manage to solve it,

```
SELECT * FROM public.app_catalog as a , (SELECT  app_id , COUNT(*) as count 
FROM public.statistics_log 
where logged_at between  '2019-08-20 12:22:40.186'   and '2019-08-22 12:22:40.186'           
GROUP BY app_id
LIMIT 10) AS App_id 
where App_id.app_id = a.app_catalog_id
```